# How do you accept a value from a user (textbox) and create a Site (when user hits Submit button) using Google Apps Script and UI Services?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following code as a Google Apps Script (deployed as a web app) and have inserted it into my Google Enterprise page as a Google Apps Script Gadget. The UI (panel) loads properly with the label, textBox and button, but when I enter in text and click the button, I get the following error: 
**Error encountered: The resource you requested could not be located.**

Here is my script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  // create all UI elements
  var myApp = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = myApp.createVerticalPanel();
  var label = myApp.createLabel('Please enter the name of your new site:');
  var textBox = myApp.createTextBox().setName('txtSiteName');

  var button = myApp.createButton('Create Site');
  var btnHandler = myApp.createServerHandler('createNewSite');
  button.addClickHandler(btnHandler);
  btnHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);

  // add all UI elements to the panel
  panel.add(label);
  panel.add(textBox);
  panel.add(button);

  // add the panel to the app
  myApp.add(panel);

  // return the app to the browser to be displayed  
  return myApp;
}

// button server handler
function createNewSite(e) {
  var domain = SitesApp.getActiveSite().getUrl();  
  var siteName = e.parameter.txtSiteName;

  var newSite = SitesApp.createSite(domain, siteName, 'script_center_demo', "this is just a test page");

  return app.close();
}
```

Also, what is the difference between `createSite()` and `createWebPage()`?

---

EDIT: Ok, so using the same `doGet()` function above, my `createNewSite()` function could look like this?

```
function createNewSite(e) {
  var domain = 'my-domain.com';  
  var siteName = e.parameter.txtSiteName;

  var newPage = SitesApp.createSite(domain, siteName, 'script_center_demo', "this is just a test page");

  var pageName = 'script_center_demo';
  var html = '<div><p>This project aims to....</p></div>';

  var site = SitesApp.getSite(domain, site);
  site.createWebPage('Script Center Demo', pageName, html);

  return app.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
var domain = SitesApp.getActiveSite().getUrl();
```

You're need to obtain a domain, e.g. `example.com`, but this line will yield a URI containing google's domain, and a resource path (that contains your domain). Example:

```
https://sites.google.com/a/example.com/mySite/
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you attempt to create a new site, it cannot be found as a *domain*. You need to strip the result of `getUrl()` down to just the domain name.

If you're the Domain administrator, you can use this instead:

```
var domain = UserManager.getDomain();
```

Ordinary domain users don't have access to the UserManager Service, so they would need to parse the site URL to extract their domain. I suggest using [parseUri by Steven Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) to handle the task:

```
var uri = parseUri(SitesApp.getActiveSite().getUrl());
var domain = parseUri(uri.path.slice(3)).host;
```

The `.slice(3)` operation is intended to remove `/a/` from the `path` property of the parsed Site URI. This works on my accounts in multiple domains today - ymmv.

After that, we treat the remaining path as a URI and invoke `parseUri()` again, extracting the `host` property, which *should* be our `domain`.

> Also, what is the difference between `createSite()` and `createWebPage()`?

You create an instance of a Site, using the Sites service method SiteApp.createSite. Not much to look at, a Site object is a container, a skeleton - you use the Site.createWebPage() method to create Web Pages that will be contained in the Site, and visible to users, mainly via web browsers.

---

#### Edit - Debugging Results

Debugging WebApps is tricky. Get familiar with "View - Execution Transcript", since it will show a trace of execution for your `createNewSite()` handler function when it's invoked. Using that technique, here's what I found, part 1:

- We can't call `SitesApp.getActiveSite().getUrl()` in the handler, because when it's invoked there is no active site. You're already using the simple work-around of hard-coding the domain.
- When trying to get a handle on the new site, you have `var site = SitesApp.getSite(domain, site);`. ***This*** is where your latest "resource error" message was coming from. The `site` parameter is left-over from insertion of the function - it needs to be a string, matching the site name used in `createSite()`.
- You're returning `app.close()`, but have no `app` defined in the function.

With those problems fixed, here's problems, part 2:

- The dialog lets users enter a site name, but there are restrictions on those that need to be followed to make `createSite` succeed. The simplest rule is that the site name must be lower case. Why not let users enter the site title, and derive the name from that?
- What if the site already exists? That's not handled. Same thing for the page creation, later on.
- There's no feedback to the user. The example below has very rudimentary status updates in it, which are appended to the UI.

#### updated code

```
function createNewSite(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var domain = 'mitel.com';
  var siteTitle = e.parameter.txtSiteName;
  var siteName = siteTitle.toLowerCase();
  var result = 'Results: ';

  var site = SitesApp.getSite(domain, siteName);  // Check if site already exists
  if (site)
    result += 'Site "' + siteName + '" exists, ';
  else {
    // Doesn't exist, so create it
    site = SitesApp.createSite(domain, siteName, siteTitle, "this is just a test page");
    result += 'Site "' + siteName + '" created with title "' + siteTitle + '", ';
  }

  var pageName = 'script_center_demo';
  var html = '<div><p>This project aims to....</p></div>';

  var page = site.getChildByName(pageName);  // Check if page already exists
  if (page)
    result += 'Page "' + pageName + '" exists, ';
  else {
    // Doesn't exist, so create it
    page = site.createWebPage('Script Center Demo', pageName, html);
    result += 'Page "' + pageName + '" created, ';
  }
  result += 'Done.';

  // Add result text to UI
  var uiResult = app.createLabel(result, true);
  app.add(uiResult);
  return app.close();
}
```